# CefGlue Running Examples on Linux

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I've downloaded the latest version of CefGlue as well as the corresponding CEF binaries. I can get the demo examples to run fine in Windows, but the Linux GtkSharp demo does not run. It compiles fine under MonoDevelop on my Linux box but throws a DllNotFoundException: libcef

I've put the libcef.so in the executable directory as well as running ldconfig in the CEF release directory.

I'm new to Linux, so there's probably something simple and obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: May I know how you get it to run? I need help on this too. please

Comment: I never did get it running on LInux - I went with Node-Webkit instead.

Comment: but you said it compiled fine under monodevelop on linux, how did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

The answers on [this Bitbucket issue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/issues/56/running-on-linux) explain how the library path resolution can be fixed.

Unfortunately, [this Bitcuket issue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/issues/108/linux-support) goes on to explain that Linux support is broken and the maintainer Dmitry says that he doesn't have the resources to support linux.